# Why are the values of my JSON objects keys undefined?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I need to parse JSON, but the values of the objects keys are undefined:

```
   const MY_JSON_FILE = "{ \"version\": \"1.0\", \"result\": 4, \"id\": \"1\" }\x00"
    
     
    
    let json = JSON.stringify(MY_JSON_FILE);
    
     
    
    const blob = new Blob([json], {type:"application/json"});
    
     
    
    const fr = new FileReader();
    
     
    
    var res;
    
    fr.onload = () => {
    
      console.log('done', fr.readyState);
    
      console.log('reader result: ', fr.result);
    
      res = JSON.parse(fr.result);
    
     
     console.log(Object.keys(res));
    
      console.log('parsed: ' + res);
    
      console.log(res.id);
    
      console.log(res.result);
    
      console.log(res.version);
    
    }
    
    fr.readAsText(blob);
```

The values of my objects keys are undefined after parsing. How can I parse and access the values of my objects keys successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You start with a string of JSON that represents an object (almost, there is some invalid data at the end).
2. You use `JSON.stringify` to convert that to a string of JSON that represents the string in 1.
3. You convert it to a file and then read it to get back to the string you had at 2
4. Your parse that string as JSON to get the string you had at 1
5. You read the Object keys of that **string**

i.e. you are encoding the object to JSON **twice** and decoding it only **once** and then trying to treat the string of JSON as the object that JSON represents.

Remove the invalid data from your original string and parse the JSON from step 4 to an object… better yet skip steps 2 and 3 entirely.

```js
const MY_JSON_FILE = "{ \"version\": \"1.0\", \"result\": 4, \"id\": \"1\" }"
const data = JSON.parse(MY_JSON_FILE);
console.log(Object.keys(data));
```